# How can I retrieve list data in Firebase Android

Tags: android

I want to retrieve data in screenshot nodes in my Firebase Real Time. How can I do that?

[This is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXeAz.png)

I have tried this

```
  mDataref.child("Game").orderByChild("ten").equalTo(ten).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            String ScreenURLdata = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("screenshot").getValue());
            Game game = new Game();
            game.setScreenshotURL(ScreenURLdata);
            String ScreenURL = game.getScreenshotURL();
            Log.d("scre",ScreenURL);
            Model_ScreenShot model_screenShot = new Model_ScreenShot(ScreenURL);
            listscreenshot.add(model_screenShot);
            adapter = new Adapter_ScreenShot(listscreenshot, getApplicationContext());
            viewPager.setPadding(-20, -15, 150, 0);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

The logcat showed this : 2019-12-03 11:36:41.443 8144-8144/com.example.gamingshop D/scre: {s1=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/skullgaming-5dab3.appspot.com/o/Game%2FBorderlands-3-screenshots-78.jpg?alt=media&token=980c6d95-f4a6-4b13-89ba-1ffec3af07d9,

s2=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/skullgaming-5dab3.appspot.com/o/Game%2Fbl3_06.jpg?alt=media&token=66a8673e-ed2e-4a23-9fff-d6ef10e16a49}

but it does not work when I try to show it to view.

Answer (score 0):

instead of  pushing data use custom Id `UUID` for unique key or use  user's id and simply fetch data using `ref.child(userid).child("screenshot")`
add read write true in storage Firebase rules